# Not uft8 on a controller with config setted on uff8

Tags: php, codeigniter, utf-8, codeigniter-3

This is the function when I use utf8 chars:

```
 private function setGeoInfo($type){   
    if($type == "1"){
        $geo = array(
            'Zona 1 - Noreste'=>array(0,0),
            'Zona 2 - Levante'=>array(0,0),
            'Zona 3 - Sur'=>array(0,0),
            'Zona 4 - Centro'=>array(0,0),
            'Zona 5 - Noroeste'=>array(0,0),
            'Zona 6 - NorteCentro'=>array(0,0),
            'Zona 7 - AMM'=>array(0,0),
            'Zona 8 - AMB'=>array(0,0)
        );
    }elseif($type == "2"){
        $geo = array(
        "Andalucía"=>array(0,0),
        "Aragón"=>array(0,0),
        "Canarias"=>array(0,0),
```

But instead of Andalucía I get Andaluc\u00eda, I thought It must be the database but  on the debug  I saw  that the array index is Andaluc\u00eda 
the project config on CodeIgniter is set as UTF-8 and the file is encoded as UTF(I tried with UTF with BOMM too).

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: That's valid escaping of UTF8, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php and `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` if you're sure your unescaped data won't be mangled in transit.

Comment: Solved, Thank you